# Ubuntu Touch HTML5 How to create a fixed header?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, html5

How can one create a fixed header when creating a Ubuntu Touch Application with the HTML5 SDK?
The api documentation does not offer any help and I could not find any HTML5 examples that were using a fixed header.

The [api](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/html5/sdk-14.10/UbuntuUI.Header/) only contains only the data-role and the id field. Nothing more to say that the header should be fiexed or default.

```
<header data-role="header" id="headerID">
</header>
```

And the only method that is defined for the header is element...

```
element( ) 
Returns the DOM element associated with the id this widget is bind to.
```

Does anyone know how this can be done in html or javascript?

EDIT:
The fact that the header has 2 modes is stated in the [design documents](http://design.ubuntu.com/apps/building-blocks/header#display-options): default and fixed.
I can confirm that these two modes really exist after using Ubuntu Touch and seeing Apps that have a disappearing header and ones with fixed headers.

Comment: This is not a generic HTML5 question, but a question regarding the HTML5 Ubuntu SDK (see link to the Ubuntu SDK api). This is nothing that exists in "normal" HTML5 because it is part of the Ubuntu SDK. So I guess here is the correct place to ask about this? If this is not the right place I'm sorry but non Ubuntu SDK users will probably not know an answer to this.

Comment: @ChristopherBludau No, you're fine. Programming questions pertaining to Ubuntu (and as such Ubuntu Touch) are considered on-topic here. Since you're using the Ubuntu HTML5 API and developing for Ubuntu Touch this question is fine here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. And thanks for the welcome. :)

Comment: @ChristopherBludau Then I have to excuse for that mistake. I am not familiar with HTML5, and did not know there are differences. I'm sorry and have deleted my comment. :)

Comment: @ByteCommander No problem :)